# Pfsense over Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, pfsense, virtual-network

Is it required to install virtual box in order to install pfsense?
I mean I would like to directy install pfsense over ubuntu 12.04 operating system without needing any virtualbox like software?

Does pfsense have capability of running over real operating system directly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which rule I have violated that makes you down voting?

Comment: The underlying assumptions of your question seem to be grossly inaccurate. This is likely leading people to downvote your question due to not meeting the `professional capacity` requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um... no.

The pfSense homepage *begins* by saying:

> pfSense is a free, open source customized distribution of FreeBSD tailored for use as a firewall and router.

It's not really designed or intended for you to install the pieces separately and "roll your own" as it were.

(And, saying FreeBSD isn't a real operating system is not only inaccurate, but insulting.)